# Toolbar can still be interacted with in Contextual ActionBar

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-toolbar, contextual-action-bar

The Contextual ActionBar doesn't integrate with the toolbar, like it did with the ActionBar. It will appear above the toolbar. This can be fixed by placing

```
`<item `name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>`
```

inside styles.xml

The problem is that while the CAB now overlays the toolbar, that's all it does. This means, that I can still interact with the toolbar when in action mode.

I have included a picture of the problem below. Here you can see that the spinner found on the toolbar, still comes up when I press area where the spinner is located on the toolbar.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you setting the `ToolBar` as the `ActionBar` using `setSupportActionBar()` or `setActionBar()`?

Comment: support AB. Here is my code: Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: @HaloMediaz can you check my answer?

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question

Comment: @ Chris Stratton done! :)

Comment: @Hey you. Undeleted it :) Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

hide the toolbar when actionmode is first created. Do not set `View.GONE`, as this will remove the space of the toolbar. Instead user `View.INVISIBLE`. This keeps the toolbar space.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_action_bar, menu);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        return true;
    }
```

Make toolbar visible when action mode is destroyed.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        this.mActionMode = null;
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: While this absolutely works it seems more like a workaround than a real solution for me.

Comment: I agree. I tried everything I could think of. This was the only thing that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `android:dropDownVerticalOffset="60dp"`

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="60dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Comment: But that doesn't fix the problem, as this doesn't disable the toolbar while in CAB.